# How to Target DOM Elements in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Within my React app, I have a sidebar which needs to have a CSS class added to it when the sidebar close button is clicked. I'm using `React.createRef()` to create a reference to the element, however, I'm receiving the following error:

[image: undefined]

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './css/Dashboard.css';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.sidebar = React.createRef();
    }

    sidebarClose() {
        console.log('test');
        this.sidebar.className += "hidden";
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="dashboard">
                <div ref={this.sidebar} id="sidebar">
                    <img width="191px" height="41px" src="logo.png"/>
                    <div onClick={this.sidebarClose} className="sidebar-close">X</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

The `console.log('test')` is just so that I can confirm the function is being executed (which it is).

Thank you.

Comment: You should be using state to control class names (and sidebar state anyways), not refs because the sidebar **inherently has state**

Comment: Yeah, check out the NPM `classnames` package. You should augment your classes in the component itself. But for refs, you would need to use `this.sidebar.current` to access it. But don't do that! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of manually trying to add a class to a DOM node, you can keep a variable in your state indicating if the sidebar is open and change the value of that when the button is clicked.

You can then use this state variable to decide if the sidebar should be given the `hidden` class or not.

**Example**

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  state = { isSidebarOpen: true };

  sidebarClose = () => {
    this.setState({ isSidebarOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { isSidebarOpen } = this.state;

    return (
      <div id="dashboard">
        <div
          ref={this.sidebar}
          id="sidebar"
          className={isSidebarOpen ? "" : "hidden"}
        >
          <img
            width="191px"
            height="41px"
            src="logo.png"
            alt="craftingly-logo"
          />
          <div onClick={this.sidebarClose} className="sidebar-close">
            X
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome.. didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to bind `sidebarClose` method to your class in constructor.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.sidebar = React.createRef();
        this.sidebarClose = this.sidebarClose.bind(this); // here
    }
```

Comment: That's true. But this is still the wrong approach for manipulating classes in React.

Comment: I know. But it answers current question and resolve problem with `undefined`